# Invoke UI from pseudo console

Tags: linux, centos, gnome, jenkins

We have some UI test cases which we are currently invoking manually on our Linux machine (with Gnome enabled). 
We login to the machine and run the below command:

```
java -jar test_case.jar
```

to invoke the test case. This opens the browser and performs the application test, and then writes the logs and quits.

Now  I am planning to automate this in a Jenkins Pipeline Job. 
But I am not sure what would be the right way to do this,
because I believe Jenkins Pipeline Job gets executed in a pseudo terminal,
whereas I believe the above command should be executed in a Gnome console.

Is there a way to automate this scenario?

Comment: You either need a "headless" browser or an X11 display available for the test process: e.g. start a `Xvfb :1 &` and set `export DISPLAY=:1` before starting the java process. Another option is using Xvnc to be able to connect remotely and see the test runs.

Comment: It is a virtual machine. Do I need to install any additional packages to start Xvfb ?

Answer (score 1):

Xvfb (X Virtual Frame Buffer) can be used for this purpose. It allows you to have a display that exists only in-memory, so that tests/operations with graphical dependencies can be completed without actually using a GUI.

On CentOS, you can install Xvfb from the core CentOS repository with yum:

```
yum install xorg-x11-server-Xvfb
```

Once Xvfb is installed, prefix your command with `xvfb-run` to use it:

```
xvfb-run java -jar test_case.jar
```

`xvfb-run` is a wrapper command that does a few useful things. First, it initializes an Xvfb display and passes it to your command for execution. Once the command runs to completion, the display is also gracefully shut down.