# Starting just an X server on a minimal installation

Tags: centos, x11, startx, xinit

I need to run a program that I haven't developed, the issue is that even if it doesn't run any GUI interface (can be used on silent mode) it still requires an X server running because of the way it's coded.

I have struggled to, not install, but go and start an X server on a Centos 7 system. **I don't want it to do anything**, just be running like on the background.

Is such a thing possible?

Comment: Use e.g. `Xvfb`, the X virtual framebuffer server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To have a GUI that exists only in memory, I would suggest using Xvfb (X Virtual Frame Buffer). [I have written an answer on this previously](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/489653/173368), so I will just reproduce the same here with some minor edits.

Xvfb (X Virtual Frame Buffer) allows you to have a display that exists only in-memory, so that tests/operations with graphical dependencies can be completed without actually using a GUI.

On CentOS, you can install Xvfb from the core CentOS repository with yum:

```
yum install xorg-x11-server-Xvfb
```

Once Xvfb is installed, prefix your command with `xvfb-run` to use it:

```
xvfb-run /path/to/your/application
```

`xvfb-run` is a wrapper command that does a few useful things. First, it initializes an Xvfb display and passes it to your command for execution. Once the command runs to completion, the display is also gracefully shut down.